# Laravel 8.x - str::markdown throws exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am using the Str helper as given below to convert markdown into Html.

```
 public static function testMarkdown()
     {
      
      $html = Str::markdown('# Laravel');
      echo $html;die;
      
     }
```

The above method is throwing an error(inside vendor\league\commonmark\src\MarkdownConverter.php )

> syntax error, unexpected 'EnvironmentInterface' (T_STRING), expecting
> function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Kindly tell me what am i doing wrong here

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Comment: @Asim PHP 7.3.21

Comment: Did you update your packages using php 7.4 or superior? If so, it's possible that composer has installed the version `^2.0.2` of [thephpleague/commonmark](https://github.com/thephpleague/commonmark) that require at least PHP 7.4 instead of `^1.3` that will works with php 7.3.